# Expose port on all interfaces using Webrick

Tags: ruby, webrick

I am new to Ruby.

I am working with a script that deploys a HTTPServer using WEBrick.

When the script runs, it logs out :

```
check_1  | [2018-12-20 17:51:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4567
```

When I do a `netstat` on the machine, I notice that the service is listening only on `127.0.0.1`

```
$ netstat -tulpn

root@c4a20aa7bd8c:/opt/service# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4567          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/ruby1.9.3
```

I want to listen on all the IPs so that I can communicate with this service from another container.

How or what configs will be necessary ?

My script definition for the server is :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby


require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?
also_reload 'config.yml'
require "sinatra/config_file"
require 'mechanize'
require "json"
require 'open-uri'
require 'mongo'
require 'uri'
require 'addressable/uri'
require 'cgi'
include Mongo
require 'nokogiri'

set :server, 'webrick'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is in the Sinatra config docs: http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

Specifically the `:bind` option. Example:  `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Setting `:bind` in the configuration doesn't seem to work if launched from "rackup", in that case, instead

```
bundle exec rackup --host '0.0.0.0'
```